# Using date in a check constraint, Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, constraints

I am trying to check add the following constraint but Oracle returns the error shown below.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD (CONSTRAINT GT_Table1_CloseDate
CHECK (CloseDate > SYSDATE),
CONSTRAINT LT_Table1_CloseDate
CHECK (CloseDate <= SYSDATE + 365)),
CONSTRAINT GT_Table1_StartDate
CHECK (StartDate > (CloseDate + (SYSDATE + 730))));
```

Error:

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint
02436. 00000 -  "date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to use a date constant or system variable,
           such as USER, in a check constraint that was not completely
           specified in a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement.  For
           example, a date was specified without the century.
*Action:   Completely specify the date constant or system variable.
           Setting the event 10149 allows constraints like "a1 > '10-MAY-96'",
           which a bug permitted to be created before version 8.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A check constraint, unfortunately, cannot reference a function like SYSDATE.  You would need to create a trigger that checked these values when DML occurs, i.e.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_check_dates
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( :new.CloseDate <= SYSDATE )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 
          'Invalid CloseDate: CloseDate must be greater than the current date - value = ' || 
          to_char( :new.CloseDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) );
  END IF;
  IF( :new.CloseDate > add_months(SYSDATE,12) )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20002, 
         'Invalid CloseDate: CloseDate must be within the next year - value = ' || 
         to_char( :new.CloseDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) );
  END IF;
  IF( :new.StartDate <= add_months(:new.CloseDate,24) )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20002, 
          'Invalid StartDate: StartDate must be within 24 months of the CloseDate - StartDate = ' || 
          to_char( :new.StartDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) ||
          ' CloseDate = ' || to_char( :new.CloseDate , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) );
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Note that for the second "constraint" LT_Table1_CloseDate, you can use a check constraint in 11g using virtual columns (http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2007/12/check-constraints-with-sysdate.html)

Answer (score 16):

You cannot use SYSDATE in check constraint. According to documentation

> Conditions of check constraints cannot
>   contain the following constructs:
>
> - Subqueries and scalar subquery    expressions
> - Calls to the functions that are **not deterministic** (CURRENT_DATE,
>     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DBTIMEZONE,
>     LOCALTIMESTAMP, SESSIONTIMEZONE,
>     **SYSDATE**, SYSTIMESTAMP, UID, USER, and 
>     USERENV)
> - Calls to user-defined functions
> - Dereferencing of REF columns (for    example, using the DEREF function)
> - Nested table columns or attributes
> - The pseudocolumns CURRVAL, NEXTVAL,    LEVEL, or ROWNUM
> - Date constants that are not fully    specified

For **10g Release 2 (10.2)**, see [constraint,](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#g1053592)  and for **11g Release 2 (11.2)** see [constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#i78179).

Remember that an integrity constraint is a statement about table data that is **always** true.

Anyway: I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve but I think you can use **triggers** for this purpose.

Answer (score 7):

Each and every time the record is updated SYSDATE will have a different value. Therefore the constraint will validate differently each time. Oracle does not allow sysdate in a constraint for that reason.

You may be able to solve your problem with a trigger that checks if CloseDate has actually changed and raise an exception when the new value is not within range.

And: What is `(StartDate > (CloseDate + (SYSDATE + 730))))`? You cannot add dates.

And: `StartDate` needs to be *after* `CloseDate`? Is that not weird?

Answer (score 5):

Write sysdate into a column and use it for validation. This column might be your audit column (For eg: creation date)

```
CREATE TABLE "AB_EMPLOYEE22"
(
   "NAME"     VARCHAR2 ( 20 BYTE ),
   "AGE"      NUMBER,
   "SALARY"   NUMBER,
   "DOB"      DATE,
   "DOJ"      DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
);

Table Created    

ALTER TABLE "AB_EMPLOYEE22" ADD CONSTRAINT
AGE_CHECK CHECK((ROUND((DOJ-DOB)/365)) = AGE) ENABLE;

Table Altered
```

Answer (score 0):

I don`t recommend sing triggers as constraint and to raise exceptions, Instead you can use a column to store **SYSDATE** as register date(if you already have it then you can use it) and then your constraint compares this column instead of **SYSDATE**

```
 ALTER TABLE Table1
 ADD (REGISTER_DATE DATE);

 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_check_dates
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
   FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   :new.REGISTER_DATE := SYSDATE;
 END;

 ALTER TABLE Table1
 ADD (CONSTRAINT GT_Table1_CloseDate
 CHECK (CloseDate > REGISTER_DATE),
 CONSTRAINT LT_Table1_CloseDate
 CHECK (CloseDate <= REGISTER_DATE + 365)),
 CONSTRAINT GT_Table1_StartDate
 CHECK (StartDate > (CloseDate + (REGISTER_DATE + 730))));
```