# compare date with current date using check constraint in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, constraints

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using date in a check constraint, Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332562/using-date-in-a-check-constraint-oracle)

using this query for making check constraint in oracle

```
alter table "ADVERTISEMENT" add constraint "ADVERTISEMENT_DATE" check ( "AD_DATE" ad_date>=sysdate) /
```

but, getting error `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`

Answer (score 2):

A check constraint is an assertion about the data which must always be true.  Consequently it makes absolutely no sense to attempt to enforce a check constrain using the current date.  Because if it is true today then it must be false tomorrow.

There are various ways around this, none of them entirely satisfactory.

You can provide a PL/SQL API to issue the insert statement, because that gives you the control to ensure that the column is always populated with SYSDATE.  Not everybody likes PL/SQL APIs.

You can define the table with SYSDATE as that column's default.  Then use permissions on the table to prevent other users populating the column.  This will only work with users other than the table owner.

You can use insert and update triggers to override any user-assigned value with SYSDATE.  But triggers have a performance impact.