# check constraint to check inserted date

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

I want to check the user's birthday should be greater than 18 years. I have used below mentioned check constraint.

```
(FLOOR((MONTHS_BETWEEN(DOB,SYSDATE))/12))>=18
```

DOB: field in table for birthdate.

but following error has occurred:

> DOB is invalid identifier.

Thanx!

Comment: can you post your table structure?

Comment: Maybe tell us about what system you're talking about?

Comment: @deceze: judging by the usage of `sysdate` that he is probably using Oracle.

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name, I think it's oracle database. It's use `MONTH_BETWEEN` and `SYSDATE`

Comment: Then someone should tag it appropriately, preferably the OP himself.

Comment: We'd need to see the table definition and the entire check constraint to spot the immediate error. But it won't work anyway, as Mike explained in his answer. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5332562/266304) for more on that topic.

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle, you can't refer to a system variable in a CHECK constraint. In fact, I'd be a little surprised if *any* SQL dbms allowed that, because it makes the constraint indeterminate.

I can think of several ways to work around it at the database level.

- Use a trigger.
- Use a foreign key reference to a table of dates that are at least 18 years before today. You'd need a job that inserts a row every day.  Time zones might give you a little trouble, though.
- Store the fact that the user claims to be at least 18 years old.

[Restrictions on CHECK constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52205)

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle documentation clearly states that only deterministic functions are allowed on check constraints; `sysdate`, `systimestamp` etc are explicitly forbidden.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#sthref2067)

One common way to work around this restriction is to leverage the data model.  For instance, does your USERS table have a REGISTRATION_DATE ?  It certainly ought to have something like that.  Naturally REGISTRATION_DATE would default to `sysdate` and, lo! your constraint becomes legal:

```
(FLOOR((MONTHS_BETWEEN(REGISTRATION_DATE, DOB))/12))>=18
```

By the way, notice that the order of arguments for `MONTHS_BETWEEN()` is (later_date, earlier date).  [Check it out](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions102.htm#sthref1257).