# How to compare new value with the previous value in oracle form field when try to edit the paticular field in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a oracle for which has a date field. This field can be null, system date, back date or future date. If it has a past date, field should not be able to modify. If it null or future date, User should be able to modify the field. How can I restrict the user if the field has a past date?

Comment: Use trigger, this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332562/using-date-in-a-check-constraint-oracle

Comment: in Oracle 11g, table level constraints is made in an indirect way , have a look at http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2007/12/check-constraints-with-sysdate.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your description correctly, you want the form field to be editable only if the current value (retrieved from the row currently stored in the database, I presume) is NULL or in the future.

To do that, I'd put some logic in the `POST-QUERY` trigger to disable the item, e.g.

```
IF :MYBLOCK.MYDATEITEM <= SYSDATE THEN
  SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('MYBLOCK.MYDATEITEM', ENABLED, PROPERTY_FALSE);
END IF;
```

There are other ways of doing the same thing, e.g. by setting the following properties:

```
IF :MYBLOCK.MYDATEITEM <= SYSDATE THEN
  SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('MYBLOCK.MYDATEITEM', NAVIGABLE, PROPERTY_FALSE);
  SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('MYBLOCK.MYDATEITEM', INSERT_ALLOWED, PROPERTY_FALSE);
  SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('MYBLOCK.MYDATEITEM', UPDATE_ALLOWED, PROPERTY_FALSE);
END IF;
```