# Oracle 11g CHECK Constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Trying to figure out why this is not working in Oracle when I am trying to create table while also creating constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT chkDOBMan CHECK (DOB < SYSDATE)
```

Inside iSQLPlus, I see following error pertaining to this line:

```
Creating Table 'tblMAN', CONSTRAINT chkDOBMan CHECK (DOB < SYSDATE)
```

> ERROR at line 13:
>   ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint

DOB column is defined as following datatype:

```
DOB TIMESTAMP
```

Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cannot use SYSDATE or SYSTIMESTAMP. Go for trigger

Answer (score 3):

`SYSDATE` is not a deterministic function - it returns different results ever time you call it, and only deterministic functions can be called from a CHECK constraint.

Check this thread: [Using date in a check constraint, Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332562/using-date-in-a-check-constraint-oracle)