# I am trying To add Check constraint for checking age and date of birth

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST"."AB_EMPLOYEE22" 
   (    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "AGE" NUMBER, 
    "SALARY" NUMBER, 
    "DOB" DATE
   ) 

alter table "TEST"."AB_EMPLOYEE22" add constraint
Age_check check((ROUND((sysdate-DOB)/365)) = AGE) ENABLE
```

But This query is not working.
Pls help me out

Comment: which database are you using??

Comment: @Nikhil Butani ...Am using Oracle database. pls help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use SYSDATE in check constraint. According to Oracle Documentation - [**Check Constraint**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52204)

> Conditions of check constraints cannot
>   contain the following constructs:
>
> - Subqueries and scalar subquery    expressions
> - Calls to the functions that are **not deterministic** (CURRENT_DATE,
>     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DBTIMEZONE,
>     LOCALTIMESTAMP, SESSIONTIMEZONE,
>     **SYSDATE**, SYSTIMESTAMP, UID, USER, and 
>     USERENV)
> - Calls to user-defined functions
> - Dereferencing of REF columns (for    example, using the DEREF function)
> - Nested table columns or attributes
> - The pseudocolumns CURRVAL, NEXTVAL,    LEVEL, or ROWNUM
> - Date constants that are not fully    specified

So, you can use `Trigger` to get your desired output in this case. Here, is the trigger which will work fine as per your requirement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_check_date
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON AB_EMPLOYEE22
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  IF(ROUND((sysdate-nvl(:NEW.DOB,:OLD.DOB))/365) <> nvl(:NEW.AGE,:OLD.AGE))
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Your Date of Birth and Age do not match');
  END IF;

END;
```

If you find any difficulty in this trigger, please feel free to write in comments.

Comment: By any chance you referred to this answer?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332562/using-date-in-a-check-constraint-oracle/5332729#5332729

Comment: Hi Nikhil, Its working fine, bt didnt get the bind parameters? what ll be the user input for it.

Comment: `:NEW.<column>` and `:OLD.<column>` are referenced as New/Old Values of column. so while compiling trigger no need to pass value and you can avoid that by pressing enter. when you perform any Insert/Update trigger will be invoked and fills the value accordingly. like if update we may have New and Old value, and while inserting we have only New value.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: *It's not a direct answer to the question.*

Now, don't store derived and most importantly constantly changing data such as `age` in the table. Instead calculate it on the fly when you query it (e.g. with a view).

```
CREATE TABLE ab_employee22
(
  name VARCHAR2(20), 
  salary NUMBER, 
  dob DATE
); 

CREATE VIEW ab_employee22_view AS
SELECT name, salary, dob,
       FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, dob) / 12) age
  FROM ab_employee22;
```

Here is **[SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97bbc/1)** demo

Comment: Of course, you do need to take account of the rest of the date and adjust with a `-1` if you want this to give the conventional age that most people would report. Otherwise, someone born on 31st December of one year is reported as age 1 the day after.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Fair enough. Updated the answer and sqlfiddle. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to user system variables like 'Sysdate' in a constraint.
Link: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:465820332843

suggestion is to use a trigger with the same logic

Answer (score 0):

Forget about having SYSDATE since its not valid or using a trigger for a workaround. I will show you a cheap trick!!!

Write sysdate into a column and use it for validation. This column might be your audit column (For eg: creation date)

```
CREATE TABLE "AB_EMPLOYEE22"
(
   "NAME"     VARCHAR2 ( 20 BYTE ),
   "AGE"      NUMBER,
   "SALARY"   NUMBER,
   "DOB"      DATE,
   "DOJ"      DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
);

Table Created    

ALTER TABLE "AB_EMPLOYEE22" ADD CONSTRAINT
AGE_CHECK CHECK((ROUND((DOJ-DOB)/365)) = AGE) ENABLE;

Table Altered
```

Comment: @user3440567 if this solution worked for you, then please mark it as correct answer or Upvote which is more polite

Answer (score -1):

You have missed an parameter of round function.

```
   alter table AB_EMPLOYEE22 add constraint
Age_check check((ROUND((sysdate-DOB)/365,0)) = AGE) ENABLE
```