# Oracle SQL Trigger errors - ORA-06512, ORA-04088

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I've got the following **trigger**:

```
create or replace trigger CHILD_DOB_TRIGGER
before insert on CHILDREN
for each row
  begin
  if :NEW.CHILD_DOB > sysdate then
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'CHILD_DOB must be greater than current date');
  end if;
  end;
/
```

But if I try to **insert**:

```
INSERT INTO CHILDREN 
VALUES ((TO_DATE('2020/05/03', 'yyyy/mm/dd')));
```

I get the following **errors**:

```
SQL Error: ORA-20001: CHILD_DOB must be greater than current date
ORA-06512: at "USER.CHILD_DOB_TRIGGER", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'USER.CHILD_DOB_TRIGGER'
```

Comment: Um, you're getting an error because your trigger raises an error if the `CHILD_DOB` column it is in the future, and you're inserting a value in the future.

Comment: What's the question here? You got what you want.

Comment: What are the ORA-06512 and ORA-04088 errors? Is something wrong with my trigger?

Comment: Also, please don't use triggers for data validation.  Use check constraints instead.

Comment: A check constraint does not work with SYSDATE and must be a trigger

Comment: For the CHILD_DOB > SYSDATE part

Comment: I wasn't aware that you couldn't use `SYSDATE` in a check constraint: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5332562/.  I do see a lot of people on SO using triggers when they should be using check constraints, sorry for assuming this was another one of those questions.

Comment: Thats okay we are all here to learn! :)

Comment: @adsdassddad There is no problem with your trigger, it exactly does what you asked it to do. The errors `ORA-06512, ORA-04088` are the part of the error stack.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your trigger. It simply threw an exception ORA-20001 because of calling raise_application_error.

Oracle in such case throws more exceptions in a stack :

you get an information, that your `INSERT` statement failed

```
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'USER.CHILD_DOB_TRIGGER'
```

next messege is where in your code exception appeared

```
ORA-06512: at "USER.CHILD_DOB_TRIGGER", line 3
```

and the last message shows main problem

```
ORA-20001: CHILD_DOB must be greater than current date
```

Answer (score 0):

> if :NEW.CHILD_DOB > sysdate then
>   raise_application_error(-20001, 'CHILD_DOB must be greater than current date');

You are raising a user-defined exception if the **new inserted date** is **greater** than **SYSDATE**.

> TO_DATE('2020/05/03', 'yyyy/mm/dd')

The above date is **greater** than SYSDATE, and thus your trigger does exactly what you asked it to do.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHILD_DOB_TRIGGER
  2  before insert on emp
  3  for each row
  4    BEGIN
  5    if :NEW.hiredate > sysdate then
  6    raise_application_error(-20001, 'CHILD_DOB must be greater than current date');
  7    end if;
  8    END;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL> sho err
No errors.
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO emp(hiredate)
  2  VALUES ((TO_DATE('2020/05/03', 'yyyy/mm/dd')));
INSERT INTO emp(hiredate)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: CHILD_DOB must be greater than current date
ORA-06512: at "LALIT.CHILD_DOB_TRIGGER", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LALIT.CHILD_DOB_TRIGGER'


SQL>
```