# How to handle relational operators for date comparison?

Tags: sql, oracle, date-comparison, relational-operators

Create table ISSUE 
( 
Lib_Issue_Id    Number(10), 
Book_No Number(6), 
Member_Id   Number(5), 
Issue_Date  Date, 
Return_date Date

```
    CONSTRAINT
        chk_issue_date
    CHECK
    (
        Issue_Date,
        ( TO_CHAR( Issue_Date, 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) <= TO_CHAR( SYSDATE(), 'yyyy-mm-dd' )
    )
)
```

Error ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

- same error with or without to_date and to_char

  - Same error when tried using alter table and add constraint

Comment: `Issue_Date` is not listed as a column in the table.

Comment: According to this QA, Oracle database `CHECK` constraints cannot use `SYSDATE`, you need to use a `TRIGGER` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332562/using-date-in-a-check-constraint-oracle

Comment: In general, in standards-compliant SQL, provided you use the correct `date`/`datetime`/`datetime2`/`datetimeoffset` (etc) types, the comparison operators `<`, `<=`, `<`, `<=`, `=`, `<>`, `!=` and `BETWEEN x AND y` are well-defined. You should always avoid converting correctly-typed date values to text in SQL.

Comment: What's a mumber data type? :P on book_no

Comment: Thank you.

My bad, I mentioned wrong table in the above question. ISSUE table is the one where I want to add check constraint. 

So I understand the fact that we cannot use sysdate. Now I am trying to put the below constraint, but still the same error. 

alter table issue
add constraint  
            chk_issue_date
        CHECK
        (
            Issue_Date,
            (  Issue_Date < return_date )
        )

ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: Insted of convert date into varchar, use trunc(issue_date) <= trunc(sysdate)