# Why can this table not be created? SP2-0042

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

Why can't I create this? I keep getting the error sp2-0042: unknown command ")"

```
 create table orders
    (
    onum number(4),
    vnum number(4),
    knum number(4),
    bedrag number(8),
    odatum date,
    constraint pk_order PRIMARY KEY (onum),
    constraint fk_order_verk FOREIGN KEY (vnum) references verkopers(vnum),
    constraint fk_order_knum FOREIGN KEY (knum) references klanten(knum),
    constraint ch_bedrag check ( bedrag > 0),
    constraint ch_date check ( odatum < sysdate OR odatum = sysdate)
    );
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Found out that it was because of the last ch_date constraint. I have to create it separately. Is there anyway how I could do this directly?

Comment: How and where are you running this? If I try it, I get:  `ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using "Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2"

Comment: To make this work I had to create a view and implement my constraint in it as following

create view c_oders
as select * from orders
where odatum < sysdate
with check option;

Comment: "sp2" indicates an SQL*Plus error, I assume. Check your code for hidden non-printables.

Comment: Check out [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52205) reference. 
Seems like you can't call functions that are not deterministic (f.e. sysdate) in a constraint.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL*PLUS

Comment: @LukStorms Thank you for the reference, I understood it

Comment: ok, btw [this old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332562/using-date-in-a-check-constraint-oracle) seems to work around that. Using a trigger, or via a column with a sysdate as default.