# Date constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, create-table

I need a check constraint for date so no data can be entered in the past. I'm using oracle live SQL for a school project and cant find a solution.

```
(BookingID Varchar2(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
App_Date Date NOT NULL, 
App_Time varchar2(8) NOT NULL,
Location Varchar2(15) NOT NULL, 
Query Varchar(50) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Check if this can help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332562/using-date-in-a-check-constraint-oracle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using date in a check constraint, Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332562/using-date-in-a-check-constraint-oracle)

Comment: Aside from your basic question, your data model is broken.  And with your repeated quesitons about mssql, I see why.  In oracle, a DATE type has - by definition - a time component, resolved down to the second.  Whether or not you use it is up to you, but it is there and is always considered part of the value of a DATE.  That said, separating app_time from app_date (assuming that app_time is the time of day of app_date) only makes your life more complex.  All of oracle's functions dealing with DATE are built with the knowledge and assumption that time of day is involved.  When in Rome ...

Answer (score 2):

Oracle interprets `check` constraints as forever constraints on the data.  That is, the check constraint is valid not only when the data changes but forever thereafter.

For this reason, Oracle does not allow volatile functions in `check` constraints.  A volatile function is one whose values can change over time.  A very good example are the date/time functions, such as `sysdate` (which is really a function without parentheses).

So, you cannot do what you want with a `check` constraint.  You need to set this up using an `insert` trigger.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know, do the microsoft sql servers also interpret the check constraints as forever constraints on the data?

Comment: @Ahmed . . . No.  SQL Server only validates the constraints when the data changes (i.e. updates and inserts).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `sysdate` in a check constraint, because, as explained by Gordon Linoff, it is a non-deterministic function (ie the value it gives is not constant over time).

Instead, you can implement the validation with a trigger:

```
create or replace trigger app_date_not_in_past
    before insert or update on mytable
    for each row
begin
    if (:new.app_date < sysdate)
    then
        raise_application_error( -20001, 'app_date date must not  be in the past' );
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, in what instance would I use a check constraint? I'm new to SQL so am not good with the terminology. Would it be used on the SQL Servers?