# Checking date atribute when creating table in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got SQL code to create table in Oracle SQL Developer and I am trying to check if value in atribute DATE is not null AND DATE <= current date + 1 year.

```
CREATE TABLE match (
ID                INTEGER NOT NULL,
DATE              DATE NOT NULL CHECK (DATE <= add_months(sysdate,12))
);
```

I am not able to run this SQL code and I still can't come up with the right solution. I got to sysdate from getdate, which supposedly doesn't work on Oracle.

Thank you for any suggestion for a solution.

Comment: similar question is replied at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5332706/1554691

Comment: Not only the fact that you cannot use SYSDATE in a check constraint (as mentioned by @CanburakTümer), "DATE" is a reserved word and so cannot be used as a column name - at least not without jumping through hoops that you shouldn't jump.  Make all your columns names in the format 'adjective_noun', and you will forever avoid the improper use of reserved words ... to say nothing of making your code more self-documenting.